# VS 2010 DB project fails to deploy after upgrade to Sql Server 2012 Error Deploy01234

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2012

I have VS2010 Premium and recently upgraded from SQL Server 2008R2 to 2012 Developer Edition. Now when I try to deploy an existing database project (created while using 2008Rs) I get the following error.

> Error {name}: The target database schema provider could not be
>   determined

Additionally, I don't see the options for creating a new database project for 2012 from the available project templates in VS, as should be available for the SQL Server Data Tools (which were installed successfully as part of the 2012 upgrade).

Comment: I had a simular issue, which turned out to be permissions based (the local installer service wich runs an MSI wich runs VSDBCMD runs under the LocalSystem account, and had no access to the remote SQL Server).

Answer (score 4):

With the help of the MS site, I was able to get this resolved.

I (re)installed SSDT from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg427686, and rebooted. Then opened SSDT up to create a new sql project. I didn't find the new project template for "Sql Server Database Project" at first - for me it appears under **Installed Templates/Other Languages/Sql Server**. Since I'm not sure if I looked there prior to this test (not an intuitive location), I can't say whether the re-install did the trick. But this got me going.

Comment: Should also note that I'm less interested in converting the dbproj now, and am creating a new project from an extract of the 2009R2 database. This was suggested by Sergey Barskiy in his post at [link](http://magenic.com/Blog/GettingStartedwithSQLServerDataToolsSSDT.aspx).

Comment: Thank you. I got the same error and installing SQL Server Data Tools and converting the project solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error to the above, when deploying database updates using vsdbcmd.

> The target database schema provider could not be determined.
>   Deployment cannot continue. {PATH and NAME} .dbschema
>
> The reference to
>   external elements from the source named {yourschema} .dbschema could
>   not be resolved, because no such source is loaded.

Example of my command:

```
/cs:"Data Source=DbServer; Integrated Security=True; Initial Catalog=Database"
```

**Trouble Shooting:**

1. Verify that you have copied all the necessary files for deploy
   program => **\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VSTSDB\Deploy**
2. Ensure you can connect to the DB server using **sqlcmd** in the exact same way you are using vsdbcmd => Integrated Security vs Username/Password
3. If you are specifying an **Initial Catalog**, remove from connection
   string and use a /p:YourDatabase

A couple of SQL commands to help test connectivity:

```
sqlcmd.exe -S tcp:<server>,<port> -Q "select getdate()"
sqlcmd.exe -S tcp:<server>\<instance> -Q "select getdate()"
```

**References:**
[vsdbcmd command line reference (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193283.aspx)
[sqlcmd command line reference (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)
http://sadomovalex.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/vsdbcmd-fix-possible-reason-for-target.html (2011)